# I cannot find small mistakes: Invalid shorthand property initializer and more

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I cannot find some mistakes I made, either punctuation or logical.
The error come when I have to push the rover coordinates and update the new position into my rover object.

Here is the guide and the code: We want to know where our rover has been so far. Create a property on the rover object that contains the coordinates of the places where it has been. This property will be an array, and you can call it travelLog.

After each move, push the coordinates of the previous place where the rover was to the travelLog array. After the rover has finished its moves, print out all of the places the rover has traveled over.(this last part I still have to code it)

```
let myRover = {
    direction: 'N',
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    travelLog = [{
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    }]
}

// ======================

function turnLeft(rover) {

    console.log('turnLeft was called!');

    switch (rover.direction) {

        case 'N':
            rover.direction = 'W';
            break;

        case 'W':
            rover.direction = 'S';
            break;

        case 'S':
            rover.direction = 'E';
            break;

        case 'E':
            rover.direction = 'N';
            break;
    }
}

function turnRight(rover) {

    console.log('turnRight was called!');

    switch (rover.direction) {
        case 'N':
            rover.direction = 'E';
            break;

        case 'W':
            rover.direction = 'N';
            break;

        case 'S':
            rover.direction = 'W';
            break;

        case 'E':
            rover.direction = 'S';
            break;
    }
}

function moveForward(rover) {
    console.log('moveForward was called');

    switch (rover.direction) {

        case 'N':
            rover.x++;
            break;

        case 'W':
            rover.y--;
            break;

        case 'S':
            rover.x--;
            break;

        case 'E':
            rover.y++;
            break;

    }

    console.log(`The rover has position: x= ${rover.x} ,  y= ${rover.y};`)

    let newPosition = x: $ {
            rover.x
        },
        y: $ {
            rover.y
        };
    rover.travelLog.push(newPosition);
}

function command(rover, orders) {
    for (let i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
        let order = orders[i];

        switch (order) {

            case 'f':
                moveForward(rover, order);
                break;

            case 'r':
                turnRight(rover, order);
                break;

            case 'l':
                turnLeft(rover, order);
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

The main main error I get is 'Invalid shorthand property initialize'

Comment: which line gives the error?

Comment: `travelLog = [{` --> `travelLog: [{`

Answer (score 1):

```
let myRover = {
    direction: 'N',
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    travelLog = [{
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    }]
```

should be

```
let myRover = {
    direction: 'N',
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    travelLog: [{ //not = but :
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    }]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem here, too:

```
    let newPosition = x: $ {
            rover.x
        },
        y: $ {
            rover.y
        };
```

I *think* you are just trying to create a new object:

```
    let newPosition = {
        x: rover.x,
        y: rover.y,
    };
```

I strongly suggst you read more about "object literal notation" and "string template literals". You seem to mix these two kinds of syntax in a way that confuses the compiler.